# Adobe Brackets: Undo (ctrl+z) does not work after save

Tags: text-editor, adobe-brackets

I am not able to undo the deleted lines or anything after saving the document `ctrl+s`

Here is the log that I have gotten by going to `Debug>show developer tools>console`

[image]

Here are the extension(s) that I am using
[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to `Debug > Reload Without Extensions`. This would solve your problem.